# Can't set up a KMM project in android studio for the first time

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin-multiplatform

I've never worked with KMM (Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile) before. I just updated to the latest version of kotlin and installed KMM Plugin in android studio then restarted android studio([Using this link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/setup.html)). Then I created a new project([using this link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/create-first-app.html)) but it gave me this error. I don't know what to do, I've tried clearing cache and restart and also tried creating another project but it still gives the same error.
I've built android apps in my android studio before with java and kotlin and it works perfectly. So maybe  this is an error of KMM or such?
[image: The Error I am getting]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the offending string like this:

`"src\androidMain\AndroidManifest.xml"`
to
`"src\\androidMain\\AndroidManifest.xml"`

i.e. add another \ with each \ in the path.

This threw me off as well, since one expects a new project skeleton to just work.

Hope this sorts it out for you, this worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are getting this error, because there is only one slash before **a** and **A** in your shared build.gradle.kts file as shown in attached screenshot. [image]

so, to solve this you need to add one more slash before both as per the attached below screenshot:

[image]

that's it!